# Добавить кнопки с меняющимся id jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой код для добавления `formset`'а для сайта. Нужно добавить кнопку удаления на каждый новый формсет. Соответственно у кнопок будет тот же `id`, что и у формсета. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать кнопки с разными `id`?

```js
$('#add_issueforinvoice').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var form_count = $('#id_invoiceforproject_set-TOTAL_FORMS').val(),
                id = '#invoice_' + (parseInt(form_count)),
                prev = parseInt(form_count),
                count = parseInt(form_count) + 1,
                form_group = $('#invoice_1');

            var new_form_group = form_group.clone().prop(
                    'id', 'invoice_' + count
            ).insertAfter($(id));

            $('#invoice_' + count).find('div').prop('id', function(index, id) {
                if (this.id)
                    return this.id.replace('set-0-', 'set-' + (count - 1) + '-');
            });

            $('#invoice_' + count).find('select').prop('id', function(index, id) {
                if (this.id)
                    return this.id.replace('set-0-', 'set-' + (count - 1) + '-');
            });

            $('#invoice_' + count).find('select').prop('name', function(index, id) {
                if (this.name)
                    return this.name.replace('set-0-', 'set-' + (count - 1) + '-');
            });

            $('#invoice_' + count).find('label').attr('for', function(index, id) {
                if (this.for)
                    return this.id.replace('set-0-', 'set-' + (count - 1) + '-');
            });

            $('#invoice_' + count).find('input').prop('name', function(index, id) {
                if (this.name)
                    return this.name.replace('set-0-', 'set-' + (count - 1) + '-');
            });

            $('#invoice_' + count).find('input').prop('id', function(index, id) {
                if (this.id)
                    return this.id.replace('set-0-', 'set-' + (count - 1) + '-');
            });
            $('#id_invoiceforproject_set-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_count) + 1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: а зачем вообще id этой кнопке? добавляй ей сразу обработчик, в котором удаляешь свежую форму и все, никаких id не нужно

Comment: @Grundy, так мне нужно удалять любую форму не обязательно свежую. Допустим я с помощью этого кода создал 4 формсета, а потом подумал и решил первый удалить, вот я кликаю на кнопку удалить ( которая по задумке на каждом формсете. и он удаляет этот формсет ( ну или хотябы отчищает и скрывает его), вот...

Comment: Так и я про то же: при создании формы, создаешь кнопку, добавляй ей сразу обработчик, в котором удаляешь форму, которую сейчас создаешь и все, никаких id не нужно

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо, сейчас так попробую)

Comment: @Grundy, я же правильно понял, в HTML создаю input с типом button и какой то надписью. а в jQuery при создании каждой формы я получаю эту кнопку через DOM и вешаю обработчик, так? или я не правильно что то понял..